# Shell script to delete messages from exim queue sent by specific authenticated user

Tags: bash, email, grep, find, exim

I found a way to find and delete from exim queue messages sent using an authenticated account (useful to purge queue from spam sent by a compromised account):

`find /var/spool/exim/msglog -exec grep -l login:email@example.com {} \; | sed 's/\/var\/spool\/exim\/msglog\/.\///' | xargs exim -Mrm`

Now I would like to write a shell script delq.sh so I can run `./delq.sh mail@example.com` to do it, but tried various combinations of quotes but was not able to make `find ... -exec login:$1 ...` working.

Answer (score 0):

At last... I was able to write the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

find /var/spool/exim/msglog -exec grep -l  'login:'$1 {} \; | sed 's/\/var\/spool\/exim\/msglog\/.\///' | xargs exim -Mrm
```

Answer (score 0):

`exiqgrep` is your friend:

```
exiqgrep -f email@example.com -i | xargs exim -Mrm
```

Comment: No, this is not what I need, I need to remove messages that were sent from a specified authenticated user, since the From: can be faked.

Comment: Sorry, the more advanced `exipick` should do the trick:
`exipick '$authenticated_id eq "email@example.com"' | xargs exim -Mrm`